# Optional chaning for javascript object destructuring

Tags: javascript, object, destructuring, optional-chaining

I have an object, and i trying to access the object properties using destructuring.
The problem is there are cases where state itself is undefined.
Hence, i wanted to add optional chaining. However, i am stuck...

```js
const {state: {one, two, three, four}} = useLocation()
```

My solution:

```js
const {state?: {one, two, three, four}} = useLocation()
```

**Problem:**
How can i add optional chaining for such syntax?

Otherwise the solution would be

```js
    useEffect(() => {
    if (!state) {
      setUserBirth(state?.userBirth);
      setUserEmail(state?.userEmail);
      setUserTel(state?.userTel);
      setUserName(state?.userName);
      setType(state?.type);
    }
  }, [state]);
```

But im wondering if i could directly apply optional chaining onto object destructuring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this

```js
const {state: {one, two, three, four} = {}} = useLocation()
```

This will at least prevent the error when the `state` is `undefined`

Comment: Does that parse?  I think it says `const { a = b } = c`